# Azure function - Method 'All' is not supported in linq query use to query cosmos db

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions-core-tools

Using the below LINQ query inside Azure function

```
var query = dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyModel>(collectionUri, feedOptions).
            Where(w => w.ParentColl.All(o => o.Value.ChildColl.Name!= null))
            .AsDocumentQuery();
```

Above query throws exception

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: MyFunction. 
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Method 'All' is not supported., 
Windows/10.0.19044 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.11.0.
```

Comment: What is happening when you replace 'All' with 'Where'?

Comment: Is it possible to put where inside where? what should be the syntax? Tried out below not working as expected, it is returning all items without applying filter.                   
               var query = dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyModel>(collectionUri, feedOptions). 
                Where(w => w.ParentColl.Where(o => o.Value.ChildColl.Name!= null) != null)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [CosmosDB v2 is deprecated and you should upgrade to a supported version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-sdk-dotnet). This would also make it easier for yourself to find examples and help, if needed.

#### Why

Regarding the exception, it is telling you that predicate `All(..)` cannot be automatically translated to a query so it could be executed on the cosmosDB back end server. Obviously `System.Linq` can do a lot more tricks than is implemented on CosmosDB v2 legacy library.

#### Workaround: SQL API

You could write your query using SQL API yourself and avoid the need to translate this predicate at all.. This is the preferred solution, imho.

#### Fix: LINQ on objects

If you really want LINQ then you should be able to apply such unsupported predicates after you fetch the results. Just apply the predicate to plain c# objects, something along the lines of:

```
var query = dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyModel>(collectionUri, feedOptions)
    .AsDocumentQuery();

while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    var results = (await query.ExecuteNextAsync<MyModel>())
        .Where(w => w.ParentColl.All(o => o.Value.ChildColl.Name!= null))
    //Do stuff with results.    
}
```

**DO note though, that you should ensure you are still filtering data on the server enough or you will be hit with bad performance and a huge RU bill.**

Comment: var query = dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyModel>(collectionUri, feedOptions) .AsDocumentQuery(); this code is going to fetch all the records . Quote "filtering data on the server enough" Unquote, how to do data filter on the server?

Comment: By passing some simpler `where`-clause before `.AsDocumentQuery()`. Similarly like you initially had.